# classicthesis header and footer odd margins

Tags: header-footer, margins, classicthesis

I'm trying to write my first document with `classicthesis` (documentclass `scrbook`), but when I compile it, it looks like the top and bottom margins are somehow reduced to nearly 0: there is nearly no space between page number/chapter title/section title and the page edge.

I progressively removed every customization I used (a couple of classicthesis options and some other packages I loaded) until I only loaded `classicthesis` and put some contents:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Title of the article}
\author{Author Name}
\maketitle

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum

\section{Bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

However, when I compile it I always get this (note - I have *not* cropped the page):

[image]

I also tried to rebuild the setup used for the package manual by adding the `drafting` option, just to check if anything changed - and it didn't even print date and time at the bottom of the page.

As far as I know, this is not exactly what `classicthesis` should produce, but I can't figure out where is the problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: `scrbook` does not seem to cooperate well with `classicthesis`. (See the bunch of warnings you get when compiling your MWE). As fas as I can tell, there are two options: You can either stick to `classithesis` and instead use a documentclass such as `book` or you could  use `scrbook` without the `classicthesis` package.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks! I was compiling with TeXstudio and as the document was compiled anyway I missed all the warnings!

Comment: Nothing to worry about. Check the options to \documentclass in classicthesis-book.tex in the Examples folder that comes with the template. You need these two options: headinclude and footinclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your \documentclass is missing two options: headinclude and footinclude. You'll find them in classicthesis-book.tex in the Examples folder that comes with the template.